# Is this a calculated field in this pivot table? How do access the formula?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm working in someone else's Excel worksheet who no longer works with us so I can't just ask them. Thanks in advance.

The sheet has a pivot table with rows that are not fields in the data. I don't work with pivot tables very often so I'm not sure if these are calculated fields? I can deduce their formula. "Start % Retained" is "Completed Readiness" divided by "Completed Start" and so on.

I had changed the name of all the "Completed" variables. They used to be (inaccurately) named "In Start" and so on, so in my new worksheet, I'm getting "#NAME?" errors, but I don't know how to access the formula to change it.

I've been searching but I think I may have the name of the concept wrong, so I'm not getting the results I need.

[image: Original pivot table]

[image: New pivot table]

[image: Pivot table fields]

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

click on a cell in the pivot table

go to pivottabletools > Options > fields items & sets

using the drop down you will be able to look at any calculated fields